# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType' in last line

Tags: python

```
def number():
    while True:
        try:
            x=float(input())
            print("Enter a number: "+ str(x))
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter a number: Error, that was not a number!")
            continue
        else:
            break
numbers = []
for x in range(3):
    numbers.append(number())
    
print(sum(numbers))
```

Error with the last line, code works fine up until then. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, the line `print("Enter a number: "+ str(x))` doesn't make sense since the user already entered a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `number` does not return a result, and by default (if one does not specify what to return), functions return `None` in python. This way list `numbers` contains `[None, None, None]` and `sum` fails to calculate it.

To return the value in this case put `return x` at the end of the function outside of the `while` loop

Comment: Thanks, did you mean right below the numbers.append line? I tried that but it says return outside of function

Comment: Try putting the return inside the function, in this case, it is the next line after `break` and intended the same level as `while` (i.e. put 1 tab or 4 spaces before it, the same way as with `while`)